# EN SQLPLUS COMO CREAR DOS TABLAS CON UNA COLUMNA CON EL MISMO NOMBRE

Tags: sqlplus

Estoy empezando con SQLPlus y me ha surgido un problema que no he podido averiguar cómo resolverlo. Tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el que tengo que crear 2 tablas. La primera es Inventario, con 2 columnas: productos, cantidad. La columna producto sería id_producto y es la clave primaria. Y la segunda tabla es la de los productos de esta primera tabla, por lo que tambien lleva una columna id_producto, que es la clave primaria. Pues cada vez que intento crear la tabla de Productos me da error de utilización del mismo nombre, y ya no sé como ponerlo, pues son la misma columna en dos tablas distintas. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si nos mostras como lo haces, te vamos a poder ayudar mas... pero suena a que estas haciendo todo en la misma tabla...